# Переадресация всех страниц через htaccess по определению языка браузера

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, редирект

Добрый день!
Копаюсь в wordpress. Для закрытия сайта от русских и украинских пользователей пытаюсь использовать данный скрипт в .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC] # что тут дописать?
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (ru|uk) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://ru.site.com/ [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://site.com/ [R=302,L]
```

В данном случае поддомен ru.site.com это страница заглушка - Maintenance mode

Вопрос: Сейчас когда пользователь заходит на site.com через русский или украинский браузер то редирект срабатывает на ru.site.com

А вот, когда переход по ссылке на страницу site.com/category/post редирект на ru.site.com не получаться.

Что нужно дописать в код чтобы пользователь попав на site.com/category/post переадресовывался на ru.site.com как это сейчас с site.com ?

Помогите решить вопрос.
Спасибо!

Comment: Уберите строку `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC] # что тут дописать?`. А две последние строки вообще не понятно зачем тут нужны.

Comment: Не помогло такое решение

Comment: Так у вас возможно браузер закешировал поведение. Попробуйте на другой странице открыть сайт или кеш браузера почистите.